# Containerized Windows build agents not starting up on AKS

Tags: windows, docker, azure-aks, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, containerd

I am trying to host a private windows build agent on AKS. I am using the dockerfile and start.ps1 script given in the official Microsoft documentation [Run a self-hosted agent in Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#add-tools-and-customize-the-container)

When i deploy the container on to our AKS client I get this
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/074fm.png)

Here is details of my setup
AKS version : 1.23.5
runtime - containerd

My deployment yaml

````
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: azdevops-win-deployment
namespace: build-agent
labels:
  app: azdevops-win-agent
spec:
replicas: 2 #here is the configuration for the actual agent always running
selector:
  matchLabels:
    app: azdevops-win-agent
template:
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: azdevops-win-agent
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: az-win-build-agent
        image: "xxxxx-acr/amie_win1:latest"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "0.5"
          limits:
            memory: "3Gi"
            cpu: "2"
        env:
          - name: AZP_URL
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: azdevops
                key: AZP_URL
          - name: AZP_TOKEN
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: azdevops
                key: AZP_TOKEN
          - name: AZP_POOL
            value: amie_win1
    nodeSelector:
      kubernetes.io/os: windows  
    tolerations:
    - key: "os"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "win"
      effect: "NoSchedule"    ```
````

I am assuming this is something to with the MS documentation being not compatible with a containerd runtime .
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does the container work when you run it locally?

Comment: @DanielMann .. locally i have a docker running ... so that works .. i have not setup containerd locally